# SELECT DISTINCT ON optimization in Postgresql 10

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I want to select last unique rows based on time, so:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (track) *
 FROM   eco.tracks WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM eco.tracks WHERE time_track < ((SELECT time_track FROM eco.tracks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)  - INTERVAL '300 seconds')  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
 ORDER  BY track, time_track DESC;
```

It gives me 20s, that too slow.
If I replace id by real value. it gives me 2ms

```
     SELECT DISTINCT ON (track) *
     FROM   eco.tracks WHERE id > 48000000
     ORDER  BY track, time_track DESC;
```

That query

```
SELECT id FROM eco.tracks WHERE time_track < ((SELECT time_track FROM eco.tracks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)  - INTERVAL '300 seconds')  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

gives only 2ms..

Whats wrong?!

Comment: Show query plans, please - EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT ... Probably Postgres cannot to optimize this query well due bad estimations. In planning time, Postgres don't know so subqueries returns 48000000

Comment: You could just run two queries instead of one. Then the optimizer can make better estimates for the second one.